# Oracle pivot within an unpivot

Tags: oracle, pivot, unpivot

I created the following query using the `UNPIVOT`. It is displaying the columns as rows which is what I wanted. I now have to include a column for 2013 along side the 2012 column. This would be a second row selected from `mytable`.

I am not sure how to do this....whether it be a pivot or a join of some sort.

This is a condensed version as mytable has 80 columns.

My query:

```
select value_type as " ", value as "2012"
  from ((select to_char(id_internal) as "ID_INTERNAL",
                to_char(tyear) as "YEAR",
                to_char(transaction_id) as "TRANSACTION_ID",
                to_char(in_date) as "IN_DATE",
                to_char(name) as "NAME",
                to_char(sid) as "SID",
                to_char(address) as "ADDRESS",
                to_char(city_state_zip) as "CITY_STATE_ZIP"
           from mytable
          where sid = 123456789
            and tyear = 2012)
        unpivot(value for value_type in (id_internal,
                               tyear,
                               transaction_id,
                               in_date,
                               name,
                               sid,
                               address,
                               city_state_zip)))
```

Desired Output:

```
                      2012                          2013
ID_INTERNAL            914008821991                 914008821991
TYEAR                  2012                         2013
TRANSACTION_ID         6402962001234                6402962001234
IN_DATE                24-JAN-14                    18-JAN-15
NAME                   BARBARA SMITH                BARBARA SMITH
SID                    123456789                    123456789
ADDRESS                123 Main Street              777 BIGSBY ST
CITY_STATE_ZIP         GREENSBORO, NC 12345-1234    CHARLESTON, SC 12345-1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like you said, you can use `pivot` or `self-join` data from two years:

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d80926/1)</sup>

Pivot version:

```
with t as (
  select * from (
  (select to_char(id_internal) as "C01_ID_INTERNAL",
         to_char(tyear) as "TYEAR",
         to_char(transaction_id) as "C02_TRANSACTION_ID",
         to_char(in_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as "C03_IN_DATE",
         to_char(name) as "C04_NAME",
         to_char(sid) as "C05_SID",
         to_char(address) as "C06_ADDRESS",
         to_char(city_state_zip) as "C07_CITY_STATE_ZIP"
    from mytable
    where sid = 123456789 and tyear in (2012, 2013))
    unpivot (value for value_type 
      in (c01_id_internal, c02_transaction_id, c03_in_date, c04_name,
          c05_sid, c06_address, c07_city_state_zip))))
select substr(value_type, 5) vt, yr_2012, yr_2013 
  from t pivot (max(value) for tyear in ('2012' yr_2012, '2013' yr_2013))
  order by value_type
```

Join version:

```
with t as (
  select * from (
  (select to_char(id_internal) as "C01_ID_INTERNAL",
         to_char(tyear) as "TYEAR",
         to_char(transaction_id) as "C02_TRANSACTION_ID",
         to_char(in_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as "C03_IN_DATE",
         to_char(name) as "C04_NAME",
         to_char(sid) as "C05_SID",
         to_char(address) as "C06_ADDRESS",
         to_char(city_state_zip) as "C07_CITY_STATE_ZIP"
    from mytable
    where sid = 123456789 and tyear in (2012, 2013))
    unpivot (value for value_type 
      in (c01_id_internal, c02_transaction_id, c03_in_date, c04_name,
          c05_sid, c06_address, c07_city_state_zip))))
select substr(value_type, 5) vt, t1.value v_2012, t2.value v_2013
  from t t1 join (select * from t where tyear=2013) t2 using (value_type)
  where t1.tyear = 2012
```